# TeamCity conditional parameter values

Tags: parameters, build, teamcity

How can I assign a runtime value to a build parameter? I set a build parameter, let's say %config.buildMode%, to a dropdown and I need to have something like an IF condition so that I can assign a different value to another parameter based on the buildmode selection.

e.g.

```
if %config.buildMode% == 'Debug'
   %config.hostName% = 'localhost'
else if %config.buildMode% == 'Release'
   %config.hostName% = 'http://servername'
else
   %config.hostName% = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

Comment: just set all parameters

Answer (score 28):

Rather late to the party, but it is possible. 
Add an extra parameter for the value you want to be conditional (e.g. TargetServerName), but leave the value blank.
Then add a powershell build step at the start of your process, and enter a script like this;

```
$BuildMode = "%buildMode%"
$ServerName = ""

if ($BuildMode -eq "Debug") {
  $ServerName = "localhost"
}
elseif ($BuildMode -eq "Release") {
  $ServerName = "theserver"
}
else 
{
exit 1
}
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='TargetServerName' value='$ServerName']"
```

The final line is the magic. By outputting that, teamcity will basically execute it, setting your TargetServerName parameter. You can then use the parameter in subsequent build steps.

Comment: For additional info, read documentation at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-changingBuildParameterAddingorChangingaBuildParameterfromaBuildStepAddingorChangingaBuildParameter

Comment: Will it change value on Parameters tab? As it can be changed somewhere in the middle

Comment: The change in value only applies for the duration of the current build, the value on the build definition will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think conditionals are possible. Ales might mean that each parameter could contain a string mashup, which could be parsed by the receiving script. For example,

```
%config.buildMode-1% == 'Debug|localhost'
%config.buildMode-2% == 'Release|http://servername'
%config.buildMode-3% == '*|http://stackoverflow.com'
```